# I can't boot into windows from grub. Only black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

As the title says, currently I'm using ubuntu 16.04/windows 8.1 and followed the recommended boot repair and now all the windows options in the grub menu all boot into a black screen. Trying to boot from f12 and selecting the os says "Windows boot manager has been blocked by the current security policy".

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9686Xzyrp2/

Please help, a lot of my work is on my windows partition and I still need to use windows for my work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem, did the recommended repair from Boot Repair and disabled my secure boot from my computer's bios settings. Hopefully another update won't mess this up again.

Comment: Just FYI that I have Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 dual boot on on hard drive with secure boot enable via EFI. Rule of thumb for installing ubuntu onto a windows computer is not to touch MBR and boot loader. Keep ubuntu in it's own partition and install grub on that partition only. Then you can chain boot to Ubuntu via window boot manager. Or use EasyBCD if you have trouble with configurating windows BCD.